# adding cells in excel with java apache

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am reading an already existing excel file and trying to add certain cells for example(C4-C15).  I am having difficult manipulating the files through java. I am using apache poi, and would appreciate any help or direction.

Comment: What is your code so far? Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26025932/1744774) and the link in the first comment to the OP there helps.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access a cell in Apache POI, you have to get a row first, and then get cell within chosen row. Below is example:

```
//Input file
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");

//Create workbook instance
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

//Create sheet instance
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

for(int i = 3; i <= 16; ++i){ //Rows from 4 to 15 (Apache POI is zero based)
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(2); //Column "C"

    //Do something with cell
}

// Write the output to a file
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

[Source (more examples here)](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook)

Comment: Oops, didn't know there's almost the same question. Hope this answer helps as well.